# What are the FLASH_ARRAY/FLASH_TABLE macros in this code?

Tags: library, flash

In this [code](https://code.google.com/p/heating-monitor/source/browse/HeatingMonitor/consts.h) for heating monitor, there appears to be macros called `FLASH_ARRAY` and `FLASH_TABLE`. I can't find any reference to them either in this code, Arduino, or on the Internet. What do they do?

```
FLASH_ARRAY(byte, VARIABLE_DEVICE_TABLE,
    DEVICE_LADDNING_RETUR,
    DEVICE_LADDNING_UT,
    DEVICE_TANK1,
    DEVICE_TANK2,
    ...
    VARIABLE_ID_LOAD,
    VARIABLE_ID_TIME_EMPTY);
```

and

```
FLASH_TABLE(byte, NUMBER_TEMP_TABLE, 7,
  {DEVICE_LADDNING_RETUR, 99,  5, 10,  7, MAIN_TYPE_TEXT_CELCIUS, 2},
  {DEVICE_LADDNING_UT,    99, 43, 10,  7, MAIN_TYPE_TEXT_CELCIUS, 2},
  ...
  {DEVICE_UTE,             0, 55, 15,  7, MAIN_TYPE_TEXT_CELCIUS_WITH_NEGATIVE, 103},
  {VARIABLE_ID_EFFECT,   114, 29, 10,  7, MAIN_TYPE_TEXT_VARIABLE, 2});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After further digging, this appears to be from Mikal Hart's [Flash library](http://arduiniana.org/libraries/flash/).

The reason this library was developed is:

> Storing static program data in flash/PROGMEM is a tricky part of
> Arduino programming. To save precious RAM, a novice user already at
> odds with unfamiliar C++ syntax must digest such daunting concepts as
> prog_char, PSTR(), PROGMEM, pgm_read_word(), etc. Even seasoned users
> get tripped up by the indirection and typecasting that are required to
> retrieve valid PROGMEM data. Add to that a couple of apparent bugs in
> the implementation, and it’s clear that PROGMEM is a complicated mess.
>
> I have written a new library, Flash, which abstracts away most of this
> complexity. It provides new String, Array, Table, and String Array
> types that make ROM-based data collections as easy to use as “normal”
> types. Each overrides the C++ [] operator, so to extract individual
> elements one uses familiar array access syntax:

Specifically, these are macros and a simple helper class to make it easier to create arrays and tables of values in program memory.

The two macros are declared as so:

```
// Example: FLASH_ARRAY(float, temperatures, 98.1, 98.5, 99.1, 102.1);
#define FLASH_ARRAY(type, name, values...) \
  static const type name##_flash[] PROGMEM = { values }; \
  _FLASH_ARRAY<type> name(name##_flash, sizeof(name##_flash) / sizeof(type));

// Example: FLASH_TABLE(uint8_t, fonts, 7, {ON, OFF, ON, ON, OFF, ON, OFF}, {OFF, ON, OFF, ON, OFF, ON, OFF});
#define FLASH_TABLE(type, name, cols, values...) \
  static const type name##_flash[][cols] PROGMEM = { values }; \
  _FLASH_TABLE<type> name((const PROGMEM type *)name##_flash, sizeof(name##_flash) / sizeof(name##_flash[0]), cols);
```

The helper functions include size and override the operator [] so that they can easily be accessed like so

```
FLASH_ARRAY[0]
```

I disagree with zmo - this is more than boilerplate. The area of PROGMEM causes a lot of questions from Arduino users, and it is very easy to do things wrong when creating arrays in PROGMEM.

Comment: Could you add an explanation of the macros within the answer? This answer contains only a link and won't be of much use, if the link goes offline.

Comment: Cybergibbons, this is nice, handy and useful, but this adds definitely a non trivial overhead: it's encapsulating an object within a full instance. When you only got 2k of RAM, every byte is precious.

Answer (score 4):

The flash array is from Mikal Hart's [flash library](https://github.com/mikalhart/Flash/blob/master/Flash.h#L39) as you show, and what it does is that they declare an array or a matrix (table) object in the PROGMEM memory:

```cpp
#define FLASH_ARRAY(type, name, values...) \
static const type name##_flash[] PROGMEM = { values }; \
_FLASH_ARRAY<type> name(name##_flash, sizeof(name##_flash) / sizeof(type));
```

which is an instance of the `_FLASH_ARRAY` class defined in that same file, which is a facility to access PROGMEM/Flash memory.

Basically, it's a lot of boilerplate for what already does the `PSTR()` macro amongst other from `pgmspace.h`. I personally would avoid using that and prefer to use the original macros along with my own index and pointers.

BTW, except for some Arduono IDE magic, I don't think that can compile, as the `Flash.h` is not included.

EDIT:

To make another point against the `FLASH_TABLE`/`FLASH_ARRAY` boilerplate/overhead, since avc-gcc 4.8 has been introduced the [`__flash` qualifier](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Named-Address-Spaces.html) which is a replacement for the `PROGMEM` macro, simplifying the whole stuff:

```cpp
// to use string literals without having to cast
#define FSTR(X) ((const __flash char[]) { X })

// create string pstr in the .progmem.data address space
const __flash char* pstr = FSTR ("foo");
```

and no more use of the `pgm_read_*()` functions, you can now access the content of the flash memory using `*pstr`, as shown is [this thread](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=1129848). In case you want to keep a code compatible with older version of avr-gcc, [here's a post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33883/embedded-conditional-code-compaction) that offers macros to deal with both systems.