# Why can I not use pointers instead of array with PROGMEM?

Tags: progmem, pointer

I'm currently changing some libraries to use flash instead of RAM for string storage so that I do not run out of SRAM on a project.

Some strings in the library are declared in this manner:

```
const char *testStringA = "ABC";
```

This is different to how I normally see this done:

```
const char testStringB[] = "DEF";
```

However, I think that these two are equivalent when declared const and initialised in the declaration. Both work fine in code.

I attempted to move these to flash:

```
const prog_char *testStringC PROGMEM = "GHI";
```

I then found that this didn't work. It was producing gobbledegook when printed.

However, following the more usual pattern of:

```
const prog_char testStringD[] PROGMEM = "JKL";
```

works fine.

I can see in the disassembly:

```
00000068 <testStringC>:
  68:   04 01                                               ..

0000006a <_ZL11testStringD>:
  6a:   4a 4b 4c 00                                         JKL.
```

So it is clear the pointer and PROGMEM results in the string/array not being initialised.

Why is this?

Example code:

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

const int BUFFER_LEN = 20;

const char *testStringA = "ABC";
const char testStringB[] = "DEF";
const prog_char *testStringC PROGMEM = "GHI";
const prog_char testStringD[] PROGMEM = "JKL";

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    char buffer[BUFFER_LEN];

    Serial.println(testStringA);
    Serial.println(testStringB);

    strncpy_P(buffer, testStringC, BUFFER_LEN);
    Serial.println(buffer);

    strncpy_P(buffer, testStringD, BUFFER_LEN);
    Serial.println(buffer);

    delay(1000);

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, this question has been wisely answered in [an answer to Stack Overflow question *C: differences between char pointer and array*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1335836/1290438).

Basically, what you're declaring as PROGMEM with,

```
const prog_char testStringD[] PROGMEM = "JKL";
```

is both the array and the memory it points to, that is, the elements of the array, both in current's scope stack. Whereas with:

```
const prog_char* testStringC PROGMEM = "GHI";
```

you declare a PROGMEM pointer to a constant string that may stay elsewhere in memory, but not declared as a PROGMEM string.

Though I did *not* test that, but you should try to declare:

```
const prog_char* testStringC PROGMEM = F("GHI");
```

to actually allocate the pointed string within the PROGMEM space. I *guess* it should be working, using Arduino's [`F()` macro](http://andybrown.me.uk/wk/wp-content/images//avr-gcc-4.7.0/WString.h), which adds a lot of boilerplate code to actually have the same result as the array declaration.

As said in comments, if not in a global context, the `PSTR()` macro could be used instead of the `F()` macro.

Simpler is better: use the array declaration, not the pointer one!

Cf [that other answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/614/379), the `__flash` qualifier is a third solution ;-)

Comment: I totally agree on the "simpler is better" - the array s far clearer. I just always get interested when something isn't immediately obvious.

Comment: F() returns FlashStringHelper which is essentially the same, but using PSTR() works fine (as long as you bring the consts inside a function).

Comment: indeed, I actually suggested first the `PSTR()` macro but changed to `F()` before submitting, because your consts are global ones in your Q, so I preferred to stick with the one that should work in both contexts.

Answer (score 3):

What this line:

```
const prog_char *testStringC PROGMEM = "GHI";
```

does is to write prologue code to copy the characters in the string to SRAM, and then initializes the *pointer* stored in flash to this SRAM location. You must load the pointer via normal means, and then dereference the pointer as usual.

```
const char *str = pgm_read_word(&testStringC);
Serial.println(str);
```

This line:

```
const prog_char testStringD[] PROGMEM = "JKL";
```

creates the *array of characters* in flash, allowing you to access it as expected.